# Export from Oracle and Import to Azure SQL reusing Entities Spring Boot

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jpa, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to fetch data from an Oracle DB and import it to Azure Sql. The databases have the same structure and therefore I was thinking if I could use the same entities and repositories with different datasources for it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Street", indexes = {@Index(name = "street_id_index", columnList = "streetid")})
public class Street {

    @Id
    private String streetid;

    public String streetcode;

    public String streetname;

    public String streetnameaddd;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "municipalitycode", referencedColumnName = "municipalitycode")
    public Municipality municipalitycode;

    public String is_deleted;

}
```

```
public interface Street_Repository extends JpaRepository<Street,String> {

    List<Street> findAll();
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AzureConfig {

    @Bean("AzureDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource-azure-sql")
    public DataSource dataSourceAzureSql(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class OracleConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource-oracle")
    public DataSource dataSourceOracle(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

```
spring:
  datasource-azure-sql:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxxxxxxxxxx-xxx;user=xxxxx@xxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=xxxxxxxx;loginTimeout=30

  datasource-oracle:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx.xx.xxx:xxx:ssid
```

```
@Repository
public class Stree_Repo implements Street_Repository {


    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("AzureDataSource")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("OracleDataSource")
    public void setDataSource2(DataSource dataSource){
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Street> findAll() {
        return null;
    }
    ... rest override methods...
}
```

So the classe Street_Repo implements the interface and because this Entity is part of both Oracle and Azure I was wondering if there was a possible of not repeating the Entity and all the other classes associated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do no think that what you are trying to do can be achieved. As far as I know, each datasource is tied to a specific repository, so you cannot have one that uses both.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yes, I've created two different packages for each one of the data sources. Package Azure with all entities and repos and the same for Oracle.